# Behaviour of the solution of $f'(x) = \beta f(x / \alpha)$ with $0 < \alpha < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations, markov-process, extreme-value-analysis

I have  a function $f(x)$ defined for $x \in [0,\, 1]$
which is such that 
$$
   f'(x) = \beta \,f(x /\alpha)
  \qquad\text{for all } x \text{ with } 0 \leq x \leq \alpha, 
$$
where $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are constants with $\beta > 0$ and $0 < \alpha <
1$.  I know that $f(0) = 0$ and that $f(x)$ is positive for $x \in
(0,\, 1)$ and infinitely differentiable on
$[0,\, \alpha]$, so that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n \geq 0$.

I conjecture that that 
$$
   \lim_{x \to 0} \;\frac{f(x) \,f(x/\alpha^2)}{f(x / \alpha)^2} = \alpha,
$$
or equivalently, that the function defined by  $g(x) := f(x)/f(x /\alpha)$ is such that $g'(x)$ tends to $0$ for $x \to 0$.  How can I prove/disprove?

Note: as a special case, we can consider the nice dilatation equation $f'(x) = f(2 x)$.

The motivation is as follows. Consider a first order autoregressive
process $Y_t = \alpha Y_{t-1} + (1 - \alpha) \varepsilon_t$ where $0 <
\alpha < 1$ and $\varepsilon_t$ is a white noise with uniform
distribution on $(0, \,1)$. Then if $F$ is the
stationary distribution function and $f(x) := 1- F(1 -x)$, the
equation above holds. My purpose is to prove that the famous *Von Mises
conditions* in Extreme Value Analysis hold, so that $F$ is in the
Gumbel domain of attraction.

Comment: Suppose that $x \in (\alpha^2, \alpha)$, then $x/\alpha > \alpha$, so how can you say that $x \mapsto f(x/\alpha)$ is again differentiable for all $x \in [0,\alpha)$?

Comment: Oh yes, "it is clear" is not true. I should replace by  "assume that" for the statement on differentiability, and then $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ remains "clear"?

Comment: Unfortunately I noticed this question only now and it is a bit later to produce the analytical details, but however have you tried to attack your problem by using the Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}[f,s]=\int\limits_{0}^\infty x^{s-1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\;?$$ This tool is sometimes very effective when dealing with the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}_+=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}|\alpha>0\}$.

Comment: Will this be better than using the Laplace transform, say $\psi$, of
$f$? A functional equation can be found for $\psi$, allowing it to be
expressed as an infinite product. But I can not see that studying the
behaviour of $\psi$ near $\infty$ will be simpler than that of $f$
near $0$. I am not a mathematician; For now, I can just show two easy things, namely that $g(x)= O(x)$ for $x \to 0$ and that the only finite limit possible for $g(x) / x$ for $x \to 0$ is $0$.